# toggleClass does't work, but addClass does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have imported jQuery and Bootstrap in my HTML page already.

Anyhoo, I wanted to toggle a dropdown menu once I click on the little menu image.

Here's how I hide my menu dropdown:

```
.menu {
  height:150px;
  width:155px;
  background-color:black;
  border-radius:5px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:100%;
  padding-left:0;
}
.menu-active {
  position:absolute;
  top:35px;
  left:60%;
}
```

To make it responsive, I first tried `addClass` (menuBtn is the button image and I got):

```
$('.menuBtn').click(function(){
  $('.menu').addClass('menu-active');
})
```

Which works pretty smooth, though it's always ignored if I added time like `addClass('menu-active', 1000)`, but this is a minor problem! I want to make it toggle, so I tried to change it to `toggleClass`:

```
$('.menuBtn').click(function(){
  $('.menu').toggleClass('menu-active');
})
```

Even when I intended to bypass toggle and just use `if` like:

```
function menuDropdown(){
$('.menuBtn').on('click', function(){
 if($('.menu').hasClass('menu-active')){
  $('.menu').removeClass('menu-active');
  }else{
    $('.menu').addClass('menu-active');
 });
}
```

Both of these don't work, the website just ignored them thoroughly.
I know bootstrap does have a simpler way to do this, I just wanna see what can I write on my own.

Comment: Not a complete answer to your question but`$('menuBtn')` is incorrect, you wanted to have `$('.menuBtn')`

Comment: ooopsie!
thx for the correction, but that's the the type i made here@@

Comment: What happens when you just `console.log('works');` inside the event handler?

Comment: This might be another typo, but you are missing a semicolon at the end of $('.menuBtn').click(function(){
  $('.menu').toggleClass('menu-active');
});

Comment: You are also missing a semicolon at the end of $('.menuBtn').click(function(){
  $('.menu').addClass('menu-active');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve the problem.  Create an ID and use that to refer to your menu instead of trying to use the menu class:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="toggler" class="menu">Menu Example</div>
<button type="button" class="menuBtn">Click me</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.menuBtn').click(function () {
        $('#toggler').toggleClass('.menu-active menu');
 });
```

Notice how the above toggles both the .menu-active and the .menu class based off of the #toggler ID.

A working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/vubsv2pt/12/

Comment: it turns out not working in my case, either. from what i understood, using a id or a class should be almost the same, right? except for html not allowing same id existing in one page?   here's how it actually is in my practice: [http://jsbin.com/mayano/edit?html,css,js,output]

Comment: it's like super messy, but i put comments as 'dropdown' in html, css and js. basically i give '#toggler' to the <ul> that i want to make toggle and change the js as in your example. when I click the menu button(it shows up when window narrow to less than 480px), nothing changed.

Comment: You need to change this part of your code to what I provided in my answer:  function menuDropdown(){
$('.menuBtn').on('click', function(){
 if($('.menu').hasClass('menu-active')){
  $('.menu').removeClass('menu-active');
  }else{
    $('.menu').addClass('menu-active');
 });
}

Comment: Aha I see - another problem is that in your HTML, you are using menuBtn twice, so that whenever you click on it once, it is actually clicking twice, meaning that it toggles the menu on and then off again:  have <span class='dropdown-toggle menuBtn' >
                  <img class='menuBtn'>

Comment: @HansLiu Here's a working example with your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/vubsv2pt/10/

Comment: @HansLiu Here's another example using jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/bejugarixi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @HansLiu I fixed the menu so that the <ul> disappears and reappears better upon clicking the menu:  http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/vubsv2pt/11/

Comment: @HansLiu Hans - if my answer solved your question, do you mind checking it as "accepted" and/or giving me an up vote?  Thanks and good luck.

Comment: It does work out! I'm extremely sorry about late reply, didn't have time to check the code out in the past week. Thank you so much for helping me!